# Handling new records in meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have "requests" collection, and I have created publications on server side and subscriptions on client side. How do I handle new records in mongodb? For example if a record was added to "requests" collection I want to get the record and perform some actions on client side. How do I do that?

Comment: This may be what you're after: http://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/a-look-at-meteor-collection-hooks/

Comment: @Avlin, did my answer solve your issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what action you want to take.

The simplest answer to this is to use a [`Tracker#autorun`](https://docs.meteor.com/api/tracker.html#Tracker-autorun)

```
Tracker.autorun(function() {
  MyCollection.find()
  // Do something here
}
```

Which will re-run whenever your collection changes.

If you are only interested in the new document you can use a [`Mongo.Cursor#observeChanges`](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Cursor-observeChanges)

```
MyCollection.find().observeChanges({
  added(id, fields) {
    //do something
  },
  changed(id, fields) {
    //do something
  },
  removed(id) {
    //do something
  },
});
```